# Diverging Gradient Boosting Optimization with custom loss

Tags: regression, machine-learning, optimization, boosting, gradient-descent

I have a supervised learning problem (regression) with $m$ input features $X=(x_1, ..., x_m)$ with output $y$.

I want to predict a "multiplicative correction factor" $\hat \alpha(X)$ such that

$$ y\approx \hat\alpha(X)x_m $$

For that I tried using Catboost (Gradient Boosting Trees) with the following loss:

$$ L(y, \hat \alpha(X)) = (\hat\alpha(X)x_m - y)^2$$

However, this leads to an unstable training:

- the loss decreases in the first steps
- then it starts to diverge very quickly

The variable $y$ takes values in $[0, 20]$ approximately and can be zero.
The variable $x_m$ takes its values in $(0, 20]$. Cannot be null.

**Question: What is causing this behavior?**
**Is there a mathematical reason this loss cannot work with boosting?**

*Note:* I managed to work around this problem by fitting $(y+1)/(x_m+1)$ (to avoid numerical issues with values close to zero). But I really want to understand this issue.

Comment: Nice question, +1. I think it is very hard to answer this as they are a lot of unknowns that might be specific to the use case at hand though. For example, it is hard to distinguish what might be CatBoost-related and what is GBM-related, have you tried XGBoost or LightGBM? Also, what is the step size used? "Quick" divergent usually related to large step sizes, (i.e. we overtake local maxima) but that's a hunch. CatBoost sets stepsize based on a heuristic usually based on the sample sizes used but what do you use? Also, how is that loss function being implemented?  (cont.)

Comment: The fact that the normalisation works might be indicative of other issues. (e.g. I suspect that using $x_m  -y$ makes the gradient higher to approximate, especially when it comes to the Newton-step) Good thinking though. :)